# lodash pick: set value if key not set

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following two arrays:

```
var headerKeys = ["title","name","address"]
var resultsArr = [
    { title:"test 1", name: "test1", unrelatedKey: "blah" },
    { title:"test 2", name: "test2" }
]
```

I'd like to clean up `resultsArr` such that it only has the keys found in `headerKeys`.
My desired output looks like this:

```
[
    { title:"test 1", name: "test1", address: "" },
    { title:"test 2", name: "test2", address: "" }
]
```

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
_.chain(resultsArr).map(function(item){
    return _.chain(item).pick(headerKeys).value()
}).value()
```

This outputs:

```
[
    { title:"test 1", name: "test1" },
    { title:"test 2", name: "test2" }
]
```

It's pretty close to what I want, but it will not show `address` since it isn't set. Is there anyway to force it to show the key even if it has no value?

Also, if you have suggestions on how to improve my lodash chain, that would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`_.defaults()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#defaults) to add the missing keys:

```js
var headerKeys = ["title","name","address"]
var resultsArr = [
    { title:"test 1", name: "test1", unrelatedKey: "blah" },
    { title:"test 2", name: "test2" }
];

/** create once the defaults object from the headerKeys **/
var defaultsObj = _(headerKeys)
  .mapKeys()
  .mapValues(function() { return ""; })
  .value();

var result = resultsArr.map(function(obj) {
  return _(obj)
    .pick(headerKeys)
    .defaults(defaultsObj) // apply the defaults
    .value();
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about `_.defaults`
Learned something new :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function `getModel()` to return your model, and then without lodash:

```js
getModel= ()=>({ title:'', name:'', address:'default' });

var resultsArr = [
    { title:"test 1", name: "test1", unrelatedKey: "blah" },
    { title:"test 2", name: "test2" }
];

var result = resultsArr.map(function(obj) {
  var model = getModel();
  for (var key in model) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      model[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return model;
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ecmascript5 alternative:

```js
var headerKeys = ["title","name","address"],
    resultsArr = [
        { title:"test 1", name: "test1", unrelatedKey: "blah" },
        { title:"test 2", name: "test2" }
    ];

resultsArr = resultsArr.map(function(o,i){
    var new_obj = {};
    headerKeys.forEach(function(k){
        new_obj[k] = o[k] || "";
    });
    return new_obj;
});

console.log(resultsArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your original code, you can add a `_.set` function within the `_.map` function: https://codepen.io/aprouja1/pen/xrzRjN?editors=0010

```
_.map(resultsArr,(el)=>{
  return _.pick(_.set(el,'address',""),headerKeys)
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do it this way since it's not dynamic enough. I don't actually know what the `headerKeys` would be at runtime.